I'm having trouble connecting my nodejs api with supabase
When trying to connect my nodejs api to supabase I receive the following error ERROR: getaddrinfo ENOTFOUND https://mmizsesimllgybfcjasy.supabase.co what could it be? Abaixo envio o codigo que faz a conexão.
const { createClient } = require('@supabase/supabase-js');

createClient(
  'Project URL', 
  'API Key'
);

const config = {
  username: 'myusername',
  password: 'mysecretpassword',
  host: 'https://mmizsesimllgybfcjasy.supabase.co',
  dialect: 'postgres',
  port: 5432,
}

module.exports = config;

I didn't quite understand what happened, it was working perfectly and nothing in the code was changed. I checked in supabase if the Project URL and API Key information would be the same and yes they did, I created a new project in supabase, tested it with the new credentials and had the same problem.
